# Is it possible to retire investing $20,000 a year for 43 years?

Tags: investing, retirement-plan

If I put $20,000 a year in a retirement fund for 43 years, is it possible to reach $1,000,000 in 43 years?and if so, what retirement funds are good to invest? And I am talking about a retirement fund that requires no interest.

Comment: $1M won't really be enough for a nice retirement in 43 years due to inflation. But, if you invest $20,000 a year for 43 years earning 4%, you will have $2M.

Comment: Would you say $2M enough is a good retirement ? By retirement, I mean a simple lifestyle.

Comment: Predicting 5-10 years out is hard enough, 40+ years is nearly impossible. Save 15-20% for retirement and you will be way ahead of most people.

Comment: I agree with Mattman944. It's impossible to predict that far in advance. Just in the past 50 years we've had numerous health tech advances (joint replacements, imaging, drugs etc) that have allowed people to live and function much longer. You might reach age 125 by then, and so you'll need 60 years worth of retirement savings after working until age 65.

Comment: What do you mean by "a retirement fund that requires no interest"? Retirement funds don't require you to pay interest; they *give* you interest.

Comment: @Sarah Smith: $2 million is way, way more than you need for a simple lifestyle - unless your idea of "simple" is just buying a new Range Rover every year, instead of whenever the ash tray is full :-)  Even at a modest 3% return after inflation, that's $60K/year AND leaves your principal untouched.  Assuming you have a paid-for house and some Social Security benefits, that's luxurious.

Comment: I am confused by the statement " And I am talking about a retirement fund that requires no interest."  Are you looking for an investment that does not earn interest (a bank account)? an investment that will never have capital gains? an investment that does not  require you to borrow money to afford it?

Comment: How much do you need to spend per year? If your income is $45,000, and you're living off of $25,000 and investing the other $20,000, your results will be different than if you are making $160,000 and only managing to save $20,000 while spending the rest.

Comment: Sarah, welcome to Money.SE. Please edit your question to focus better on what You'd like us to address. It feels like there are 2-3 questions here, for now, try to focus on the one thing that we can answer, and then perhaps post another question if needed. The first line of the body of your question is a math problem. But with no background on your situation, how can we know if $1M nearly a half century hence, is enough for you to retire on?

Answer (score 0):

Well, $20000 a year for 43 years is $860000. In today's dollars that amount of money at 3.5% dividend produces an annual income of $30100.

If the investment only keeps up with inflation through the 43 years, it will pay an annual income in future dollars equal to the buying power in today's dollars of $30100. The future dollars will be a bigger number than today's dollars but the buying power will be about the same.

So the investor should decide if they want to take the risk of trying to outperform inflation or if they want the lower risk of just trying to keep up with inflation.

Now actuarial calculations could be done on paying down the total amount after retirement. But as the amount is paid down then the dividend income also gets smaller. And the actuarial assumptions are a risk.

Comment: Are you presenting a "worst-case" scenario? Setting aside money for 40+ years in CDs or Money Market, but having no investment that beats inflation?  "Now actuarial calculations could be done on paying down the total amount after retirement." What does this mean? Pay down what?

Comment: Keeping up with inflation is not a worst-case scenario. However, I recommend trying to beat inflation with investments in equity-income categories.  "Pay down" refers to spending some of the nest-egg after retirement rather than using it solely to produce dividend income.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. When I enter a post-inflation 7%, I see just shy of $5M. And $200K/yr withdrawal rate. Which results in quite a range of potential outcomes.  And why we need to understand a lot more about the OP.